# I don't get any response from server, How can I fix this?

Tags: ios, alamofire

I have a networking in a simple login screen. I used Alamofire and Decodable. I don't get any response from server. Why could that be? (I added ATS code to info.plist)

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

struct ResponseLogin: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let surname: String
    let email: String
    let password: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func loginButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Button Pressed")

    guard let email = emailTextField.text else {return}
    let url = "URL"
    let body = ["email": email]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: body, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in

        if response.result.error == nil {
            print("No Response Error")
            guard let data = response.data else { return }
            print(data)
            do {
                let responseLogin = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseLogin.self, from: data)
                print(responseLogin)

            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
            }

        } else {
            debugPrint(response.result.error)
        }
    }

}
}
```

Web Service:

[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void getUserDetail(string email)
    {
        userDetail user = (from c in DBcontext.users
                           where c.Email == email
                           select new userDetail()
                           {
                               id = c.id,
                               name = c.Name,
                               surname = c.Surname,
                               email = c.Email,
                               password = c.Password
                           }).SingleOrDefault();

```
    string jsonstr = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(user);
    Context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    Context.Response.Write(jsonstr);
    Context.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: anything in console?

Comment: Wrong url, server is down,... It could be anything so you need to supply more information like any error message etc

Comment: Just this standard code:  2018-11-24 16:53:49.614188+0300 TestApp[1320:172080] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2018-11-24 16:53:49.617853+0300 TestApp[1320:172080] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.

Comment: I checked everything. Url is correct and it works on Postman

Answer (score 0):

There might be possible many issues in API calls.

First, you can check your API is working or not, check on Postman. If API is working fine on postman then you should check in your code.

And are you sure your backend server is running?

Comment: I checked it on Postman it works fine. Yes backend is running also